# When the key is a tuple in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, lowercase

I'm having troubles understanding this. I have a dictionary, where the key is a tuple consisting of two strings. I want to lowercase the first string in this tuple, is this possible?

Comment: Once you create the tuple you can't change it, so you ve to check before creating the tuple.

Comment: @user2795095, is it a constraint that you want to fix the keys in the old dict, because you seem to imply that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a tuple is immutable, you need to remove the old one and create a new one. This works in Python 2 and 3, and it keeps the original dict:

```
>>> d = {('Foo', 0): 0, ('Bar', 0): 0}
>>> for (k, j), v in list(d.items()): # list key-value pairs for safe iteration
...     del d[k,j] # remove the old key (and value)
...     d[(k.lower(), j)] = v # set the new key-value pair
... 
>>> d
{('foo', 0): 0, ('bar', 0): 0}
```

Note, in Python 2, dict.items() returns a list copy, so passing it to list is unnecessary there, but I chose to leave it for full compatibility with Python 3.

You can also use a generator statement fed to `dict`, and let the old dict get garbage collected. This is also compatible with Python 2.7, 2.6, and 3.

```
>>> d = {('Foo', 0): 0, ('Bar', 0): 0}
>>> d = dict(((k.lower(), j), v) for (k, j), v in d.items())
>>> d
{('bar', 0): 0, ('foo', 0): 0}
```

Comment: Python 2 says, "Using `iteritems()` while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a `RuntimeError` or fail to iterate over all entries." Python 3 says the same for `items()`, "Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a `RuntimeError` or fail to iterate over all entries."

Comment: Hi, @SteveJessop, good catch, I tested it and it worked fine for this use-case, but I don't want to lead people astray for other use-cases, so I edited it in the safe direction as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dict comprehension to build a new dict with your changes applied:

```
d = { (a.lower(), b) : v for (a,b), v in d.items() }
```

Comment: "modified" is probably the wrong word.  It's a new `dict` assigned to the original name.  That should be just fine if the local name is the only reference.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: By "modify" here I mean applying a pure function to it (so the old value is still preserved). Agreed that it collides with the meaning of mutation. What do you think would be a better term?

Comment: I would just use "new".

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the string to lowercase before putting it into the tuple.  Tuples are read-only after they are created.

Comment: You can always create a new dict representing changes you want

Comment: Okei, thank you for the answer. I'm importing a word-tagg corpus from brown which comes in tuples, so I don't see how I can change this before putting it in the dictionary...

Comment: Although, this really doesn't have much to do with the tuple being immutable -- The problem is really that the *string* is immutable.  (mutating an object in a `tuple` works just fine).

Comment: If you already are given the populated dictionary, I suppose you could iterate through each key/value, create a new key using the lowercase version of the string, insert the new key with the same value, and remove the original pair.

Comment: @mgilson even if strings were mutable, mutating it would break the hash table invariants. It's a good thing python doesn't let you use mutable objects as keys

Comment: @aldo you would typically just use a dict comprehension for that and leave the old dict be

Comment: @NiklasB. -- the default `__hash__` for user defined classes is the instance `id` -- So you *can* use mutable objects as dictionary keys even though it is against common wisdom to do so.  However, my point was really to point out how `tuple` work so as to not propogate any misunderstanding about that part.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are "immutable", which means you cannot change a tuple in place after it is created.  However, you can make a new tuple by modifying the existing tuple.   I used the word "immutable" because that is the Pythonic word, better than "read only".

Lists are mutable.   Interestingly enough, strings are immutable, but that rarely causes any problem.

Comment: A new tuple cannot be used as key for the existing value because it will have another hash.